# Calculate Fleiss Kappa with annotator replacement

Tags: mathematical-statistics, agreement-statistics, cohens-kappa

If three annotators, A, B, and C, label 180 data, In the middle of the labeling process, C is replaced with D, and A, B, and D label 200 data. Can it count and average for three labelers as whole 380 data with three annotators with Fleiss Kappa? How many annotators in the matrix for this case can calculate 380 data according to that situation?

Answer (score 0):

For A and B you can use all the data, but I don't see any reason that you should able to substitute D for C. They are different people, they will rate differently and, if you simply combine them, your kappa will be a mishmash.

You have four raters, not three.

Of course, you can make a program do what you propose -- just relabel D as C and bingo!  But that would be deceitful.